# If $q$ is the quotient and $r$ the remainder when $a$ is divided by $b$, $r \geq q$, prove that $q$ is the quotient when $a$ is divided by $b+1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, contest-math

I have some 'intuition' on this, but I can't translate it into a rigorous form. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;a = bq+r=(b+1)q + r-q\,$.

Answer (score 1):

So, we have $a=bq+r$ and $q\le r<b$.

Let $r'=r-q$.

Now, we can write $$a=bq+q+r'=(b+1)q+r',$$ and it follows from above that $$0\le r-q=r'<b-q<b+1.$$ (This means $r'$ is a valid remainder term).

Thus, $q$ is the quotient when $a$ is divided by $b+1$.